# Is it possible to pickle Python object by reference (by name)?

Tags: python, celery, pickle

I have a situation where there's a complex object that can be referenced by unique name like `package.subpackage.MYOBJECT`. While it's possible to pickle this object using standard pickle algorithm, resulting data string will be very big.

I'm looking for some way to get same pickling semantic for an object that is already here for classes and functions: Python's pickle just dumps their fully qualified names, not code. This way just string like `package.subpackage.MYOBJECT` will be dumped and upon unpickling object will be imported, just like it happens for functions or classes.

It seems that this task boils down to making object aware of variable name it's bound to, but I have no clues how to do it.

Here's short example to explain myself clearly (obvious imports are skipped).

File bigpackage/bigclasses/models.py:

```
class SomeInterface():
    __meta__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def operation():
        pass

class ImplementationA(SomeInterface):
    def operation():
        print "ImplementationA"

class ImplementationB(SomeInterface):
    def operation():
        print "ImplementationB"

IMPL_A = ImplementationA()
IMPL_B = ImplementationB()
```

File bigpackage/bigclasses/tasks.py:

```
@celery.task
def background_task(impl, somearg):
    assert isinstance(impl, SomeInterface)
    impl.operation()
    print somearg
```

File bigpackage/bigclasses/work.py:

```
from bigpackage.bigclasses.models import IMPL_A, IMPL_B
from bigpackage.bigclasses.tasks import background_task

background_task.submit(IMPL_A, "arg1")
background_task.submit(IMPL_B, "arg2")
```

Here I have trivial background Celery task that accept one of two available implementations of `SomeInterface` as an argument. Task's arguments are pickled by Celery, passed to a queue and executed on some worker server, that runs exactly the same code base. My idea is to avoid deep pickling of `IMPL_A` and `IMPL_B` and instead pass them as `bigpackage.bigclasses.models.IMPL_A` and `bigpackage.bigclasses.models.IMPL_B` correspondingly. That will help with performance and total traffic for queue server and also provide some safety against changes in `IMPL_A` and `IMPL_B` that will make them non-pickleable (for example lambda anywhere in object attributes hierarchy).

Comment: I do not think that's what `pickle` was designed for. If the type of your `package.subpackage.MYOBJECT` is an instance (not a class), you could also save only the name `package.subpackage.MYOBJECT` and later import it again.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm sort of forced to use pickle. This question appeared in the context of Celery serialization. Of course I can explicitly pass a name of an instance to class constructor, but it will make such instances harder to move around between packages, something that we tend to do a lot. I have a hope that there's some way to infer this name automatically.

Comment: It may help us suggest solutions, @Michael, if you'd produce a minimal code snippet/script, that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @boardrider, thank you for suggestion. I've updated my original question with example.

Comment: Do you have a single or at least limited number of "dictionaries" where named objects may be found? If not, do you have a way to somehow register such objects, so some central place knows about the named objects (but probably not about unnamed temporary ones)?

Comment: @doublep, I don't have such container, unfortunately. No entity is aware of these objects, except for Python itself.

Comment: @MichaelKorbakov: I believe what you want is not possible then. At best you can get a *list* of objects from some GC hacking (certainly not in a cross-implementation way), but there is no way to find what refers to those objects.

Comment: @doublep, the best thing I can think of is analyzing current_frame in constructor. There I'll have access to original line of source code and split it by "=". That will give me name of a variable and module is easily accessible. But such approach seems to be incredibly fragile. May be some AST manipulation can do the trick in less fragile way.

Comment: @MichaelKorbakov: I'd much rather use some custom registration machinery than rely on such things, even if you get them to work.